# Generate backup with ZipArchive

Tags: php, oop, zip, php-ziparchive

i try to write a script, with which will generate backup for directory.
I write this, but not work ... can't create zip file :S
Maybe it's wrong, in my OOP style, i still newbie :-)

[Pastebin Code](http://pastebin.com/hwS1JgW3)

Comment: Please add some meaningful error messages. What goes wrong?

Comment: What does this line echo ( $this->zip->open(self::$backup,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) == true ? 'true' : 'false'); display in your code?

Answer (score -1):

Without trying to fix your code,

Please see post from: *peter at boring dot ch*
at http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfile.php

Hopefully solves your needs.

regards,

//t

Comment: Nothing wrong, when i open a file it's blank.  echo ( $this->zip->open(self::$backup,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) == true ? 'true' : 'false'); is for test, but show true. I test this code, but not work, i wonna edit my class.